# Kotlin View setEnabled function missing?

Tags: android, kotlin

In **Kotlin**, when using `kotlinx.android.synthetic` to access the `View` (e.g. `Button`), the `setEnabled()` function is missing? The `isEnabled()` function is still there.

How could I `setEnabled()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As said [in the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters), Java getters and pairs of getter and setter are represented as properties in Kotlin, using the following logic:

- `T getSomething()` (+ `void setSomething(T)`) → `something: T`
- `T isSomething()` (+ `void setSomething(T)`) → `isSomething: T`

If there is a setter, a `var`-property is seen from Kotlin, otherwise it's an unmodifiable `val`.

Instead of `setEnabled(value)` just use `isEnabled = value`.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 7):

Apparently we now set it using

```
button.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Oh, now everything is a property.