# Kotlin invoke getter/setter reflectively

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Beginner in Kotlin here.

I try to create and populate objects by reflection in a program. I cannot find the equivalent functionality in pure kotlin so my solution resembles the code below which works fine, but requires the use of dirty references like `java.lang.String::class.java` and intelliJ, understandably, doesn't seem to like this. Is there a simpler way that I am missing to do this?

```
val jclass = myObject::class.java 
val setters = jclass.declaredMethods.filter { it.name.startsWith("set") }
for (s in setters) {
    val paramType = s.parameterTypes.first()
    val data = when(paramType) {
        java.lang.Integer::class.java -> foo
        java.lang.Double::class.java -> bar
        java.lang.String::class.java -> baz
    }
    s.invoke(myObject, data)
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use Kotlin reflection, which requires you to add `kotlin-reflect` as a dependency to your project.

<sup>Here you can find `kotlin-reflect` [for Kotlin 1.0.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.0.5-3), or [pick another version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) if you use different Kotlin version.</sup>

After that, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
val properties = myObject.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties
for (p in properties.filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()) {
    val data = when (p.returnType.javaType) {
        Int::class.javaPrimitiveType,
        Int::class.javaObjectType -> foo
        Double::class.javaPrimitiveType,
        Double::class.javaObjectType -> bar
        String::class.java -> baz
        else -> null
    }
    if (data != null)
        p.setter.call(myObject, data)
}
```

Some details:

- Despite using Kotlin reflection, this approach works with Java classes as well, their fields and accessors will be seen as properties, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37481421/2196460).
- Just like with Java reflection, `memberProperties` returns `public` properties of this type and all its supertypes. To get all the properties declared in the type (including the `private` ones, but not those from the supertypes), use `declaredMemberProperties` instead.
- `.filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>` returns only the mutable properties, so that you can use their `p.setter` later. If you need to iterate over the getters of all the properties, remove it.
- In the `when` block, I compared `p.returnType.javaType` to `Int::class.javaPrimitiveType` and `Int::class.javaObjectType`, because what's `Int` in Kotlin can be mapped to either Java `int` or `java.lang.Integer` depending on its usage. In Kotlin 1.1, it will be enough to check `p.returnType.classifier == Int::class`.

Answer (score 1):

If You need to get property getter/setter, there is a couple of built-in constructions for it YourClass::propertyName

have a look at example bellow

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val myObject = Cat("Tom", 3, 35)
        println(Cat::age.getter.call(myObject)) // will print 3
        Cat::age.setter.call(myObject, 45)
        print(myObject) // will print Cat(name=Tom, age=45, height=35)
    }

    data class Cat(var name : String, var age : Int, val height : Int)
```

but sometimes you don't know class exactly(working with generics) or need to get list of properties, then use `val <T : Any> KClass<T>.declaredMemberProperties: Collection<KProperty1<T, *>>` it will return all properties, some of them can be mutable(var) and some immutable(val), you can find out immutability by checking belonging to `KMutableProperty<*>` (by filtering with `is` operator or using convenience methods such as `filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>`)

about your code snippet

I absolutely agree with hotkey, but now it is better to use `myObject::class.declaredMemberProperties`  instead of `myObject.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties`

because the second one is deprecated

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html

```
     data class Cat(var name : String, var age : Int, val height : Int)

     @JvmStatic
            fun main(args: Array<String>) {
                val myObject = Cat("Tom", 3, 35)
                val properties = myObject::class.declaredMemberProperties
                for (p in properties.filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()) {
                    val data = when (p.returnType.javaType) {
                        Int::class.javaPrimitiveType,
                        Int::class.javaObjectType -> 5
                        String::class.java -> "Rob"
                        else -> null
                    }
                    if (data != null)
                        p.setter.call(myObject, data)
                }
                println(myObject)
                // it will print Cat(name=Rob, age=5, height=35),
                // because height isn't var(immutable)
            }
```

in general, I would approach similar problems with such construction in mind

```
val myObject = Cat("Tom", 3, 35)

Cat::class.declaredMemberProperties
                    //if we want only public ones
                    .filter{ it.visibility == KVisibility.PUBLIC }
                    // We only want strings
                    .filter{ it.returnType.isSubtypeOf(String::class.starProjectedType) }
                    .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
                    .forEach { prop ->
                        prop.setter.call(myObject, "Rob")
                    }

println(myObject)
//it will print Cat(name=Rob, age=3, height=35),
//because name is only eligible in this case
```