# ClassMapper: No setter/field for aBooleanType

Tags: android, firebase, gson, kotlin

I am using firebase and this is my data class definition:

```
data class ClaimOrder(val address: String? = null,
                  val amount: Long = 0L,
                  val isProcessed: Boolean = false,
                  val onCreate: kotlin.Any? = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
```

however on logs I am seeing following warning: `W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for isProcessed found on class com.guness.bitfarm.service.models.ClaimOrder`

I have tried `@SerializedName("isProcessed")` but no luck.

Comment: `val` is used to declare read-only property. You have to use `var` to provide setter for that property.

Comment: @BakaWaii also tried that, interestingly I am seeing only for `isProcessed`

Comment: Oh, see if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481017/kotlin-view-setenabled-function-missing) is related.

Comment: @BakaWaii could be related, found what is wrong, variable name `isProcessed` is wrong. probably underlying gson and kotlin generates/expects different names.

when I use `processed` in both kotlin and firebase, problem seems resolved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find any official document from Firebase mentioning about the naming rules of the getter and setter, but it seems like they are looking for [JavaBean-like getters/setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37514605/8343333)

When you have a property named `isProcessed`, Firebase requires you to have getter/setter named `getIsProcessed()`/`setIsProcessed()`. However, a different naming rule is applied when the property is start with `is` in Kotlin. It genarates getter/setter named `isProcessed()`/`setProcessed()`, according to [Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties):

> If the name of the property starts with `is`, a different name mapping rule is used: the name of the getter will be the same as the property name, and the name of the setter will be obtained by replacing `is` with `set`. For example, for a property `isOpen`, the getter will be called `isOpen()` and the setter will be called `setOpen()`. This rule applies for properties of any type, not just `Boolean`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the exact reason but here is my guess:

variable name `isProcessed` causes different accessor methods to be generated so underlying `gson` and `kotlin` methods does not match.

however using just `processed` seems to fix things well.

Comment: correct, it seems that firebase does not detect 'is' prefix setters fields for data classes.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason even if I left out the `is` in front of the variable name it still wouldn't parse. Instead I solved it by just making a custom constructor like so:

```kotlin
data class User(
    var uid: String? = null,
    var isDeveloper: Boolean? = null,
    var email: String? = null
) {
    constructor(dict: Map<String, Any>) : this() {
        this.uid = dict["uid"] as? String
        this.isDeveloper = dict["isDeveloper"] as? Boolean
        this.email = dict["email"] as? String
    }
}
```

Which I parsed like so:

```kotlin
documentSnapshot.data?.let {
    completion(User(it), null)
    return@addOnSuccessListener
}
```

Although it's probably not the best solution if you need a massive constructor but for small data classes it works fine :)